# decodeURIComponent is not doing it's job

Tags: flash, flash-builder

A string is send from the server to the app, it contains special characters from different languages, decodeURIComponent is throwing error messages every time a special character from a different language appears in the string, any idea how to deal with this issue?

Comment: Show example of such string, then also show current result vs expect result.

Comment: Have you realized now that `decodeURIComponent` does **not** throw error(s) when a string has foreign characters? Example of `https%3A%2F%2Fwww.谷歌.com%2F` when parsed with `decodeURIComponent` gives no error and result of `https://www.谷歌.com/`... Since you didn't tell us what your _"special character from a different language"_ means, then no-one can help you. Tell us the error and what string caused it. How to reproduce your issue?